# Updating SQLite with AJAX data: how to handle two asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to update SQLite with some JSON data fetched via AJAX.
This is my progress so far.
The problem is that this function always returns false. I know that this is because of the second asynchronous execution of the db.transaction. How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance!

```
function updateDb(url) {
    $.ajax({url: url,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            ajax.parseJSONP(result);
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            console.error('Network error while fetching IR JSON!');
        }
    });
    var ajax = {  
            parseJSONP:function(result){
                var db = window.openDatabase("Test", "1.0", "Test DB", 100000);
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

                function populateDB(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testtable;');
                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable (id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, testtext TEXT)');
                    $.each( result, function(i, row) {
                        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO testtable (id, testtext) VALUES (' + row[0] + ',\'' + row[1] + '\';'); 
                    });
                }

                function errorCB(err) {
                    console.error("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);
                    return false;
                }

                function successCB() {
                    console.info("Updating DB successful!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) - you've declared but not used `var success = false;` (2) Shouldn't you be `return`ing the value of `ajax.parseJSONP(result)`? A function that returns no result can't return a value that will generally test as being true.

Comment: (1) That's just an artefact, I've deleted it in the sourcecode.
(2) I use the callback functions of db.transaction...

Comment: Ah, okay. I still don't think that's it with the callbacks and the 'always false' result. What if you change `success: function (result) {
            ajax.parseJSONP(result);
        },` to `success: function (result) {
            return ajax.parseJSONP(result);
        },` - I.e the callback functions give parseJSONP it's return value. Buuuuut that return value is discarded, hence the above suggestion.

Comment: Nope.
I just did some additional debugging: the outer success callback finishes _before_ the inner successCB. Therefore, no return value...

Comment: :( Sorry for what's turned out to be a wild-goose-chase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this by using two callbacks, one to parseJSONP and one to the success callback.
I think this is a valid solution, however, I really hate navigating only by callbacks.